# Find the words that start with a vowel in the first sentence, and the words that end with a vowel in the second sentence

Tags: c, string, for-loop, char, strcat

There are two sentences. How to Create a third sentence consisting of the words beginning with a vowel in the first sentence and the words ending with a vowel in the second sentence?

I have example for input/output. Output need in one line.

input:
Sentence1(printf)='The main building material **is** Kentish rag-stone, **although** some local mudstone was **also used**'

Sentence2(printf)="As **the** building was intended **to be a comfortable residence** as well as **a** stronghold"

output:

*"is although also used / the to be a comfortable residence a"*

//words from 1st sentence start with a vowel, and words from 2nd sentence end with a vowel

I tried something:

void main()

{

```
int i, j=0, k=0, l, l2;
char text1[200], text2[200], text3[400], text4[200];
puts("Introduceti text1");
gets(text1);
puts("Introduceti text2");
gets(text2);
l=strlen(text1);
for(i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    if(text1[i]==' ') continue;
    {
        if(text1[i]=='a' ||text1[i]=='e' || text1[i]=='i' || text1[i]=='o' || text1[i]=='u')
        {
            text3[j]=text1[i];
            j++;
            i++;
            do
            {
                text3[j]=text1[i];
                j++;
                i++;
            } while(text1[i]!=' ');
            text3[j]=' ';
            j++;
            text3[j]=' ';
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            while(text1[i]!=' ')
           i++;
        }
    }
}
l2=strlen(text2);
for(i=l2-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if(text2[i]==' ') continue;
    {
        if(text2[i]=='a' || text2[i]=='e' || text2[i]=='i' || text2[i]=='o' || text2[i]=='u')
        {
            text4[k]=text2[i];
            k++;
            i--;
            do
            {
                text4[k]=text2[i];
                k++;
                i--;
            } while(text1[i]!=' ');
            text4[k]=' ';
            k++;
            text4[k]=' ';
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            while(text1[i]!=' ')
           i--;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n");
strrev(text4);
strcat(text3,text4);
printf("%s",text3);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too broad for SO and does not show any effort yet. This seems to be homework. Normally homework assignments are related to the topic that was discussed during previous lessong. There you should get some starting point. Then if you can't solve everything, show us what you have tried so far and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Could you please remove the empty lines from your code? Please prepend code with 4 spaces to make or click the `{}` button while editing to make it appear in nice code-blocks. Code looks ok, but notes: - a string is a __zero__ terminated array of characters. You need to `text4[k+1]='\0';` mark an end to the string, same with `text3[j+1]='\0'`. The `if(text2[i]=='a'` checks if the first character is a vowel - you need to check the last. I guess you could just `strrev(text2)`. And: `strrev` is not standard extension and `gets` is deprecated, use `fgets`. Use meaningfull names for variables.

Comment: What goes wrong when you run your code? ([Edit] that into your question. It helps us help you.)

Comment: @usr2564301 when i run my code, in the example above I get: "is  although  also  used  be  a  omfortable   as  a". Something is wrong and i not understand what

Comment: English language is tricky. How does, "A thing. Work?" How about; semicolons?